# Promisifying a Passport Strategy with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise, ecmascript-6, passport.js

I'm trying to clean up my authentication to use `Promise` rather than having several nested callbacks. I managed to do it when my function involved simple Mongoose queries, but have been stuck trying to apply a `Promise` to my `Passport.js` `Strategy`.

Would really appreicate some help with converting my `localLogin` function into a `Promise` based function as me and my ESLinter are not too happy with the multiple `return done(...)` calls.

Here's the code:

```
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (clientPassword, callback) {
  bcrypt.compare(clientPassword, this.password, (err, isMatch) => {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    return callback(null, isMatch);
  });
};

const localLogin = new LocalStrategy(localOptions, (username, password, done) => {
  User.findOne({ username }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return done(err);
    if (!user) return done(null, false);

    user.comparePassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) return done(err);
      if (!isMatch) return done(null, false);

      return done(null, user);
    });
  });
});

passport.use(localLogin);
```

This is then used as middleware like so:

```
const requireLogin = passport.authenticate('local', { session: false });

router.route('/login')
  .post(requireLogin, authController.login);
```

Comment: seeing as `localLogin` simply instantiates a `LocalStrategy` object, I don't think it will be as simple as you may think ... what do you do with the `localLogin` object after this code snippet?

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry, added how it's used above in the post.